# How to fix 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to pull the names of current U.S. members of Congress from [https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22:[%22117%22%2C%22118%22]%7D&pageSize=250&page=1&searchResultViewType=expanded&KWICView=true](https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22:%5B%22117%22%2C%22118%22%5D%7D&pageSize=250&page=1&searchResultViewType=expanded&KWICView=true). I'm leveraging the code I found [here](https://github.com/lobodemonte/big-data-for-public-policy/blob/master/congress_gov_scraper/congress_gov_scraper.ipynb) and it's exactly the same, but I keep getting the `NoneType` error when I call get_num_pages.

I thought that was because the page_num_element wasn't returning anything, but when I look at the source code of the website I can't see anything wrong with why it wouldn't work. See snip below:

[image: congress source code]

Here's the code:

```
import json
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

congress_numbers = [117,118]
page_size = 250

def get_congress_url(congress_numbers, page_size, page):
    congress_q_str = "{" + '"congress":[{}]'.format(','.join('"{0}"'.format(num) for num in congress_numbers)) + "}"
    params= {
        "q": congress_q_str,
        "pageSize" : page_size,
        "page" : page,
        "searchResultViewType": "expanded",
        "KWICView": "true"
    }
    actual_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params, safe='{}:[]')
    return "https://www.congress.gov/members?{}".format(actual_params)

def get_num_pages(soup):
    page_num_element = soup.find("div", {"class": "basic-search-tune-number"}).find("div", {"class": "pagination"}).find("span", {"class": "results-number"}).text
    page_num_raw = [int(s) for s in page_num_element.split() if s.isdigit()]
    return int(page_num_raw[0])

def extract_member_name_url(entry):
    result_heading = entry.find("span", {"class": "result-heading"})
    member_name = result_heading.text
    if "Representative" in member_name:
        member_name = member_name.replace("Representative", "").strip()

    elif "Senator" in member_name:
        member_name = member_name.replace("Senator", "").strip()
    
    url = result_heading.a['href']
    return [member_name, url]   

def extract_congress_members(congress_list):
    members = []
    for entry in congress_list:
        member = {}
        [member["name"], member["url"]] = extract_member_name_url(entry)
        
        members.append(member)
    return members

#Now that we know how many pages we'll scrape, we can start scraping
congress_url = get_congress_url(congress_numbers, page_size, 1)
print("Congress URL: ", congress_url)

response = requests.get(congress_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

#We need the number of pages we will need to scrape
num_pages = get_num_pages(soup)
print("Number of result pages: ", num_pages)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better check your `response` / `soup` to get an idea - Your code becomes outdated because site is checking for javascript, that is not supported by `requests`.

So you may use [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/) to mimic browser behaviour, wait for rendering of content, clicking next page if available, wait for `actionLoaderWrapper` to be gone and repeat.

Just a simple example, to outline the basic steps:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

url = f'https://www.congress.gov/members?q=%7B%22congress%22%3A%5B%22117%22%2C%22118%22%5D%7D&pageSize=250'
driver.get(url)
data=[]
while True:

    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.actionLoaderWrapper')))

    items = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-results-wrapper ol.basic-search-results-lists li.expanded')))
    for e in items:
        ## perform actions on the elements that are needed ...
        d = {
            'name':e.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.result-heading a').text.split(' - ')[0]
        }
        d.update(dict(x.text.strip().split(':',1) for x in e.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.result-item')))
        data.append(d)
        ## just for demonstration purpose, to get all results from each page, dissolve the release the "handbr(e)ake"
        break

    try: 
        print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.next[href]').get_attribute('href'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.next[href]'))).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
driver.close()

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | name | State | District | Party | Served |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Adams, Alma S. | North Carolina | 12 | Democratic | House: 2014-Present |
| 1 | Herrera Beutler, Jaime | Washington | 3 | Republican | House: 2011-2023 |
| 2 | Rutherford, John H. | Florida | 5 | Republican | House: 2017-Present |

...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the long expression

```py
page_num_element = soup.find("div", {"class": "basic-search-tune-number"}).find("div", {"class": "pagination"}).find("span", {"class": "results-number"}).text
```

After split this for a few small expressions as

```py
    one = soup.find("div", {"class": "basic-searchone-tune-number"})
    two = one.find("div",
                   {"class": "pagination"})
    page_num_element = two.find(
        "span", {"class": "results-number"}).text
```

I got an error

```
    two = one.find("div",
          ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

**This means there isn't any div.basic-searchone-tune-number in the soup.**

```py
import urllib

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

congress_numbers = [117, 118]
page_size = 250


def get_congress_url(congress_numbers, page_size, page):
    congress_q_str = "{" + '"congress":[{}]'.format(','.join('"{0}"'.format(num) for num in congress_numbers)) + "}"
    params = {
        "q": congress_q_str,
        "pageSize": page_size,
        "page": page,
        "searchResultViewType": "expanded",
        "KWICView": "true"
    }
    actual_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params, safe='{}:[]')
    return "https://www.congress.gov/members?{}".format(actual_params)


def get_num_pages(soup):
    one = soup.find("div", {"class": "basic-searchone-tune-number"})
    two = one.find("div",
                   {"class": "pagination"})
    page_num_element = two.find(
        "span", {"class": "results-number"}).text
    page_num_raw = [int(s) for s in page_num_element.split() if s.isdigit()]
    return int(page_num_raw[0])


def extract_member_name_url(entry):
    result_heading = entry.find("span", {"class": "result-heading"})
    member_name = result_heading.text
    if "Representative" in member_name:
        member_name = member_name.replace("Representative", "").strip()

    elif "Senator" in member_name:
        member_name = member_name.replace("Senator", "").strip()

    url = result_heading.a['href']
    return [member_name, url]


def extract_congress_members(congress_list):
    members = []
    for entry in congress_list:
        member = {}
        [member["name"], member["url"]] = extract_member_name_url(entry)

        members.append(member)
    return members


# Now that we know how many pages we'll scrape, we can start scraping
congress_url = get_congress_url(congress_numbers, page_size, 1)
print("Congress URL: ", congress_url)

response = requests.get(congress_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

# We need the number of pages we will need to scrape
num_pages = get_num_pages(soup)
print("Number of result pages: ", num_pages)
```